# Create a TimeSerie using an index and values from different TimeSeries, with different indices

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series

I want to create a DataFrame or TimeSerie using an index of an existing TimeSerie and the values from another TimeSerie with different time indices. The TimeSeries look like;

```
 <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
DT
2018-01-02    172.3000
2018-01-03    174.5500
2018-01-04    173.4700
2018-01-05    175.3700
2018-01-08    175.6100
2018-01-09    175.0600
2018-01-10    174.3000
2018-01-11    175.4886
2018-01-12    177.3600
2018-01-17    179.2500
2018-01-18    180.1000
...
```

and

```
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
DT
2018-01-02        NaN
2018-01-09    175.610
2018-01-16    177.360
2018-01-23    180.100
...
```

I want to use the index from the first TS and fill it with the values from the second TS. If an index can't be found in the first TS, it should use the next available date in this TS. Like;

```
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
DT
2018-01-02   NaN
2018-01-03   NaN
2018-01-04   NaN
2018-01-05   NaN
2018-01-08   NaN
2018-01-09   175.610
2018-01-10   NaN
2018-01-11   NaN
2018-01-12   NaN
2018-01-17   177.360
2018-01-18   NaN
...
```

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My idea is to use [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reindex.html) twice:

```py
second_ts.reindex(first_ts.index, method='ffill').drop_duplicates().reindex(first_ts.index)
```